# Looking for SQL query LIKE ('1077%') operator ON DATA

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-like

Looking for sql query for LIKE ('1077%') operator ON following DATA (ONE ROW).

```
   Postalcode             Range_From        Range_To      // (columns name)
    Dubai                  10777            10985         // (data,table row)
```

Result should be (First 3 rows)

01 - Dubai    10777 
  02 - Dubai    10778 
  03 - Dubai    10779 
  04 - Dubai    10780 <   // It shouldn't include in result because it doesn't meet like criteria
  05 - Dubai    10781 <   // It shouldn't include in result because it doesn't meet like criteria
  06 - Dubai    10782 <   // It shouldn't include in result because it doesn't meet like criteria
  .........

Comment: have you tried any query?

Answer (score 0):

if range-from is not a string kind of type

```
select * from tableName where CAST(Range_From AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE '1077%'
```

try this then

```
Declare @fromRange int
Set @fromRange=10770
Declare @toRange int
Set @toRange=10780
        ;WITH CTE_Numbers AS (
        SELECT n = @fromRange
        UNION ALL
         SELECT n + 1 FROM CTE_Numbers WHERE n < @toRange
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_Numbers num where CAST(n AS VARCHAR(9)) LIKE '1077%'
```

MySQL:

```
SET @starts = 10777-1;

SELECT  @n := @n +1 AS vals
FROM mysql.help_relation , (SELECT @n:=@starts) tab where @n like '1077%' LIMIT 10 ;
```

Comment: Vivekh - In my example. There is only on record in table and I want to generate 3 records(see example output that I mentioned in question) from this one record based on like operator('1077%'). Your query doesn't

Comment: That's not valid for MySQL

Comment: Vivekh - I'm using MySQL.So I can't use 'common table expression' :(. I have tagged it with MySQL too

Comment: Yes there is mysql but your question says "Looking for SQL query for"

Answer (score 0):

It was simple.

```
select * from tableName where Range_From LIKE '1077%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableName where Range_from between 10770 and 10779
```

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to retrieve the data but generate it?Because you said your table has only that one row.
So what you can do is, create a sequence which start with 10777 and max value as 10779
then you may use the sequence to display result